# Published report can't connect to data source after I change the data source

Tags: tableau-api

I updated a report with embeded data, from SQL Server, to our company's Tableau Server. It worked perfectly. After that, the old SQL Server is going to be demised, thus I move all data to a new server, the database, schema and data are exactly the same, and update the data connection in my local reports. It still works well.

Then I publish it again with the same configuration. The publishion is successful. However, Tableau server shows error that the database can't be connected when I open the report. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

I just update the server, username and pass for all data connections.

[image]

**Exception**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the Tableau Server does not have access for extracting data from the new server. Our Tableau Server will need a new account for the new server to extract data I needed. Thus, I need to raise a ticket to create such account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working from a published data source and you change information, such as the server connection details, you should re-upload the new data source - you may wish to also delete the old data source to avoid confusion.

Comment: I embeded the data source when I publish the workbook. I am wondering whether it is a server permission or configuration issue. I created another test workbook connecting to the new server and it works well in my local PC. The same issue happened after I published it.

Comment: Have you embedded the permissions into the new workbook when you publish?

Comment: Yes, I embeded the password.